# How to create a new object with new refrence of an existing object java

Tags: java

I called the removeAll method to remove from my tempDictionary but it removes from d. So how can I avoid privacy leak and assign new refrence to tempDictionary.

```
public static void play1(Dictionary d,  int level )throws IOException
{
  Dictionary tempDictionary  = d ;
  tempDictionary.removeAll();
}
//after looking to the link doesn't compile  I tried to do exact same 

class  Dictionary {
private Dictionary dictionary; public Dictionary(Dictionary temp ) {
this.dictionary = temp.dictionary; // error 

}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: class  Dictionary {
  private Dictionary dictionary; public Dictionary(Dictionary temp ) {
    this.dictionary = temp.dictionary; // gonna work ?? 
  }
}

Comment: In copy constructor you should assign fields of class Dictionary, not the object itself. How do you implemented Dictionary class?

Comment: e.g. `public Dictionary(Dictionary otherDict) { this.someField = otherDict.someField; }`

Comment: this is my dictionary class :    public class Dictionary
    {
     private  ListOfNodes[] data  = new ListOfNodes[26];

   //Constructor
   public Dictionary()
   {
     inData();
     AssignLetters();
   }

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
   Dictionary tempDictionary  = d ;
```

what you actually do is that you create a second dictionary reference that points to the existing one(in your case d).
So every action that you perform at tempDictionary affects d too because both point to the same object.
To solve this you can copy the components of d to a new dictionary do what you want to the copy.

EDIT: I used the instance keyword in the previous answer which is wrong because a new instance is created with the new keyword.What i meant is reference.Thanks to Amer Qarabsa and Tokazio for pointing out.

Comment: its a variable of type Dictionary not , some may call it mistakenly reference to a Dictionary instance , but its completely wrong to say its an instance, instance = object

Comment: can you please tell me what u mean by copy ?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I don't understand what you are trying to say, please explain were i am wrong.

Comment: @Anny I mentioned in a comment on your question a possible duplicate , you need to clone your object.

Comment: @Anny You can copy the components of a dictionary by value into a new dictionary so that you wont  affect the original.

Comment: @theVoid well you said  "you create a second dictionary instance that points to the existing one" , this is misleading, instance = object so you are basically saying that and object of type Dictionary is pointing to another object and this is not correct. what happened here is you have a variable of type dictionary not instance

Comment: a second dictionary REFERENCE not instance. The 2 references are pointing to the same instance.

Comment: ok I got what said but problem is how can I copy each element of Dictionary class as it has a lot? should I create a class ?

Comment: @Anny One way is to clone the object as mentioned by Amer Qarabsa.

Answer (score 0):

Use java reflection to proceed to the deep copy of the fields recursivelly. or use existing library like kryo